# Insert with Select clause Nodejs query string

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following query:

```
var query2 = "INSERT INTO abonnement (type_carte,type_demande,type_abonnement,classe,date_validite,gare_depart,gare_arrivee,id_client) VALUES ('"+t_carte+"','"+t_demande+"','"+t_abonnement+"','"+classe+"','"+date_validite+"','"+g_depart+"','"+g_arrive+"','SELECT id_client from client WHERE id_client=8')";
```

But when I execute it I receive the following error:

> mysql ERROR : Incorrect integer value : 'select id_client from client where id_client = 8 ;

FYI , `id_client` is a `foreign key` from table client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `id_client` field you have to pass out put of the `select` statement but not the statement itself as a ***'string literal'***. Remove the surrounding single quotes and just put parenthesis.

```
 var query2 =
  "INSERT INTO abonnement (type_carte, type_demande, type_abonnement
                         , classe, date_validite, gare_depart
                         , gare_arrivee, id_client)
   VALUES ( '" + t_carte + "','" + t_demande + "','" 
               + t_abonnement + "','" + classe + "','" 
               + date_validite + "','" + g_depart + "','" 
               + g_arrive 
               + "', ( SELECT id_client FROM client 
                        WHERE id_client = 8 LIMIT 1 )
          )";
```

I have added `LIMIT 1` clause, because in case if the statement returns more than a single record, your query would fail.

**PS**: When you already know value of `id_client` field, why are you using `select id_client ... where id_client=8 ...` statement? You can directly input `'8'` in place of this unnecessary statement.

Comment: Thx dude ,  And yes you right but instead 8 i will make a variable , if have any idea how to replace 8 with variable like t_carte and t_demande etc ... help me .. :)

Comment: It is as similar as you assigned values to other variables and used in the query.